# Php code between Tab Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to insert php code in between tabby tabs shortcodes.

I am using a plugin [tabby tab](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tabby-responsive-tabs/)  for tab view and have added this code in my theme template:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[tabby title="Gallary Name"]
  name content 
  [tabby title="Images"]

  [tabbyending]'); ?>
```

I want to use a custom fields gallery under images tab using code like this:

```
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[tabby title="Gallary Name"]
  name content 
  [tabby title="Images"]

<?php 
$i = 0;
$images = get_field('vil_pics');
if( $images ): ?>
 <div>
   <ul>
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
            <li<?php if ( $i % 3 == 0 ) echo ' class="break"' ?>>
                <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                     <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                </a><p>.</p>
                            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul></div> 
<?php endif; ?>

[tabbyending]'); ?>
```

This code is not working, it's showing a blank page. How can I fix this?

Comment: One issue is one line 1 of both you're doing `echo`. You'll want to compile everything and spit it out then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabby uses a global variable to track what's going on, so I think either one of these will work. The first one is a little more straightforward, but the second one will definitely work.

**Option 1:** output everything in order:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[tabby title="Gallery Name"] name content' );
echo do_shortcode( '[tabby title="Images"]' );

// your php code as-is
$i = 0;
$images = get_field('vil_pics');
if( $images ): ?>
  <div>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ):
          $i++ ?>
          <li<?php if ( $i % 3 == 0 ) echo ' class="break"' ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
              <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
            </a><p>.</p>
          </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </div> 
<?php endif;

echo do_shortcode( '[tabbyending]' );
```

**or Option 2:** save everything to a variable and output it all at once:

```
$output = '';

$output .= '[tabby title="Gallery Name"] name content';
$output .= '[tabby title="Images"]';

$i = 0;
$images = get_field('vil_pics');
if ( $images ) {
  $output .= '<div><ul>';
    foreach( $images as $image ) {
      $i++;
      $li_class = ( $i % 3 == 0 ) ? ' class="break"' : '';

      $output .= '<li' . $li_class . '>';
      $output .= '<a href="' . $image['url'] . '">';
      $output .= '<img src="' . $image['sizes']['thumbnail'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" />';
      $output .= '</a><p>.</p></li>';
    }
  $output .= '</div></ul>';
}

$output .= '[tabbyending]';

echo do_shortcode( $output );
```

Note that I didn't see anything increasing `$i` so I added that. Everything else is as-is.